# Using buttons in detailview to gothrough masterTableView, but buttons disappear when value is greater/less than # of rows intableview

Tags: ios, swift

Beginner here - I have a TableViewController that prints a story in a DetailView.

I have successfully implemented Last and Next buttons in my DetailView Tab Bar that when tapped, print the story at the row - 1 or row + 1 currently indexRow value. I have set the Last button to disappear at the first Row and the Next button to disappear at the last Row.

However, when I'm in DetailView and navigate Next and Last and reach the last row or first row, the Last or Next disappear respectively, and they do not come back. I suspect its due to how I've frame the if statements and need some help with fixing this. Can someone tell me the error?

Another related issue I'm having is that if you select the first or last row in the TableView, the DetailView loads with the Last or Next and these only disappear if I navigate away from the first or last story and back to the first or last story. What is the best way to solve this?

Here is my code so far.

```
Class DetailViewController: UIViewController: {

var selectedStory : URL!
    var selectedIndex: Int!
    var stories: [URL] = []
@IBOutlet weak var lastLabel: UIBarButtonItem!
@IBOutlet weak var nextLabel: UIBarButtonItem!

//MARK: - Tab Bar Next/Last Toolbar button actions
@IBAction func lastButton(_ sender: Any) {
    if ((self.selectedIndex - 1) < self.stories.count) {
        self.selectedIndex = self.selectedIndex - 1
        let nextStory = self.stories[self.selectedIndex]
        DispatchQueue.global().async {
            let nextStoryText = try? String(contentsOf: nextStory)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.textView.text = nextStoryText
            }
        }
        let storyTitle = nextStory.deletingPathExtension().lastPathComponent
        storyTitleLabel.title = storyTitle
    }

    if selectedIndex == 0 {
        lastLabel.title = ""
    }
        else {
        lastLabel.title = "Last"

    }
}

@IBAction func nextButton(_ sender: Any) {
    if ((self.selectedIndex + 1) < self.stories.count) {
        self.selectedIndex = self.selectedIndex + 1
        let nextStory = self.stories[self.selectedIndex]
        DispatchQueue.global().async {
            let nextStoryText = try? String(contentsOf: nextStory)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.textView.text = nextStoryText
            }
        }
        let storyTitle = nextStory.deletingPathExtension().lastPathComponent
        storyTitleLabel.title = storyTitle     
    }
    if ((self.selectedIndex + 1) == self.stories.count) {
        nextLabel.title = ""
    }
        else {
        nextLabel.title = "Next"

    }
}
}

class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

var stories: [URL] = []

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DetailVC") as? DetailViewController {
            vc.selectedStory = stories[indexPath.row]
            vc.stories = stories
            vc.selectedIndex = indexPath.row

            navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Please share the code handling the button.. You are changing the text of label, Are you placing the button over the label?

Comment: `self.stories.count - self.stories.count` will always produce `0`, so you could just go for `if selectedIndex == 0 {...}`. Now I don't know what last and next labels `title` property is because it's obviously your custom solution. So the problem might be with how this title is set.  In general I would suggest going for `if index == 0  { label.text = "" else { label.text = "Last" } `

Comment: From logical point of view, your both button titles should be updated in both `nextButton` and `lastButton`functions.

Comment: @inokey Both are added as titles in storyboard as Last and Next. I updated my code with your if index == 0 { label.text = "" else { label.text = "Last" } but it still does not reappear after it disappears. Any other ideas I could try?

Comment: @anuraj the buttons are UIBarButtonItem iboutlets

Comment: Your problem is that you need to restore titles in all the cases. In your code you set nextButton title when it's being hit. But after it's gone you will never tap there again, so the button doesn't know when to show it's title again. Add some function to restore titles when specific state is reached.

Comment: @bhealth Please try to name the components with respect to the class. Naming uibarbutton as label caused the confusion.

Comment: @anuraj Ahh I see. Thank you for this!

Comment: @bhealth I think its better to enable and disable uibarbutton rather than changing the title. Because even if the title is empty, it will get the click event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to change the user interaction rather than changing the title

```
@IBAction func lastButton(_ sender: Any) {
        if ((self.selectedIndex - 1) < self.stories.count) {
            self.selectedIndex = self.selectedIndex - 1
            let nextStory = self.stories[self.selectedIndex]
            DispatchQueue.global().async {
                let nextStoryText = try? String(contentsOf: nextStory)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.textView.text = nextStoryText
                }
            }
            let storyTitle = nextStory.deletingPathExtension().lastPathComponent
            storyTitleLabel.title = storyTitle
        }

        changeTheBarButtonUserInteraction()

    }

@IBAction func nextButton(_ sender: Any) {
    if ((self.selectedIndex + 1) < self.stories.count) {
        self.selectedIndex = self.selectedIndex + 1
        let nextStory = self.stories[self.selectedIndex]
        DispatchQueue.global().async {
            let nextStoryText = try? String(contentsOf: nextStory)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.textView.text = nextStoryText
            }
        }
        let storyTitle = nextStory.deletingPathExtension().lastPathComponent
        storyTitleLabel.title = storyTitle     
    }
 changeTheBarButtonUserInteraction()

}

func changeTheBarButtonUserInteraction(){

lastLabel.isEnabled =  selectedIndex != 0 ? true : false
nextLabel.isEnabled =  ((self.selectedIndex + 1) == self.stories.count) ? false : true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@IBAction func lastButton(_ sender: Any) { if ((self.selectedIndex - 1) < self.stories.count) { self.selectedIndex = self.selectedIndex - 1 let nextStory = self.stories[self.selectedIndex] DispatchQueue.global().async { let nextStoryText = try? String(contentsOf: nextStory) DispatchQueue.main.async { self.textView.text = nextStoryText } } let storyTitle = nextStory.deletingPathExtension().lastPathComponent storyTitleLabel.title = storyTitle } if selectedIndex == 0 { lastLabel.title = "" } else { lastLabel.title = "Last" }  nextLabel.title = "Next"}

@IBAction func nextButton(_ sender: Any) { if ((self.selectedIndex + 1) < self.stories.count) { self.selectedIndex = self.selectedIndex + 1 let nextStory = self.stories[self.selectedIndex] DispatchQueue.global().async { let nextStoryText = try? String(contentsOf: nextStory) DispatchQueue.main.async { self.textView.text = nextStoryText } } let storyTitle = nextStory.deletingPathExtension().lastPathComponent storyTitleLabel.title = storyTitle } if ((self.selectedIndex + 1) == self.stories.count) { nextLabel.title = "" } else { nextLabel.title = "Next" }lastLabel.title = "Last"} }
```

> But it would be better if you hide and show the button because it may be possible if button have width then  user is still able to press.
>
> If you still facing difficulties please let me know.